# Remove inner double quote in CSV file

Tags: java, regex, csv

I have a CSV file which contains double quote inside the data.

> EI_SS
>   EI_HDR,"Test FileReport, for" Testing"
>   EI_DT,tx,tx,tx,tx,tx,tx,tx,tx,tx,tx,tx,tx,tx,tx,tx,dt8,tx
>   EI_COL,"Carrier, Name","Carrier ID","Account Name","Account ID","Group Name","Group ID","Action Code","File ID","Contract","PBP ID","Response Status","Claim Number","Claim Seq","HICN","Cardholder ID","Date of Service","NDC"
>   "Test Carrier" ,"MPDH5427" ,"1234" ,"CSNP" ,"TestD" Test" ,"FH14077" ,"" ,"PD14079042" ,"H5427" ,"077" ,"REJ" ,"133658279751004" ,"999" ,"304443938A" ,"P0002067501" ,01/01/2014,"50742010110" ,"C" 
>   "Test, Carrier1" ,"BCRIMA" ,"Carrier" ,"14" ,"123333" ,"00000MCA0014001" ,"" ,"PD14024142" ,"H4152" ,"013" ,"REJ" ,"133658317280023" ,"999" ,"035225520A" ,"ZBM200416667" ,01/01/2014,"00378350505"

The Updated Actual CSV

Now I want to remove the inner quotes from these data but need to keep outer double quotes for each data.

For processing file, I have used `"\"[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+[,][ a-zA-Z0-9]+\""` pattern to split the file. But if there is any inner quote in any row then the code breaks.

I need to convert this into XLSX by keeping comma's and replacing inner quotes (if not possible then removing those inner quotes.

Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: easy enough to replace '\" ' - but is this enough?

Comment: This is not a valid CSV file. Solution: fix the system that produces this output.

Comment: Hi Java1, I need to keep outer quotes. Hi Duncan, now I have provided real data.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is not possible, because the way you demarcate two values is ambiguous. For example, how to split the following value?

```
""I am", "a single", ", value""
```

Is it meant to be:

```
I am
a single
, value
```

or

```
I am
a single, , value
```

or even

```
I am, a single, , value
```

?

Comment: +1 This is the problem. The input file is not valid CSV, it's ambiguous and parsing will be impossible.

Answer (score 0):

first of all why don't you use the proper char of regex ?

actually there is a char : `\w` which means `[a-zA-Z_0-9]` instead of your `[a-zA-Z0-9]` (quite the same just adding _ but much more readable I think ^^)

For your pattern, as other said, the best way is to correct the way you generate the csv at first ;)

Comment: Hi Clad, I will definitely try with \w. But this doesn't solve my problem. I have to keep commas intact and also remove inner quotes.

Answer (score 0):

If your data is having just one double quote: ,"abc "def", - Following should help:

test.txt
"abc","def"gh","ijk"
"lmn","o"pq","rst"

sed -i 's/([^,])\"([^,])/\1\"\"\2/g' test.txt

Command above looks for a set of 3 characters which matches a pattern - ?"? where ? is anything but a comma. Implies - search for 3 characters which is not like ,", and replace " with ""

Command split:
([^,]) - character that is not a comma - () are for remembering this character
\" - Double quote
\1 - First character which is remembered
\2 - Second character which is remembered.

Note: This does not work if you have two double quotes in the encapsulated. The above command does not escape " in ,"a"b"cc",

Hope this helps a bit.